# Can anyone explain how wishlist mage-cache-storage data update on every add product on wishlist in magento2?

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I want to refresh wishlist `mage-cache-storage` data (for remove product from wishlist on product detail page)same like does on add product on wishlist.

Has anyone know how **data refresh** of `mage-cache-storage` of wishlist?

Can you please explain.

[image]

Comment: Create observer using this event `controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove` now you can refresh `mage-cache-storage` programatically there

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati    Do you know the flow off add product on wishlist mage-cache-storage?

Answer (score 0):

When you adding or remove items in Wishlist or Cart it doing ajax request or  straight load another url in your tab to process you request on backend. And also happens local storage sections invalidation from js on FE, it tells your browser that section in local storage should be updated and does ajax request for that. You can open tab network in developer console in google chrome and filter the XHR requests with "?section" and you will be able to see the response data which should be replace in your local storage sections.